# How to send post to Facebook from PHP?

Tags: php, facebook

I want to send post on FACEBOOK page from php....
I tried this way, the massage that I got was "successful", but nothing in my facebook page.

Please help me, I need help.
thanks!

Why I can't send massage on Facebook from PHP??

```
<?php
// require Facebook PHP SDK
require_once("facebook.php");


$config = array();
$config['appId'] = '!!!app_ID!!!';
$config['secret'] = '!!!SECRET_ID!!!';
$config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

$fb = new Facebook($config);

$params = array(
  "access_token" => "!!!PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN!!!",
  "message" => "TITLE",
  "description" => "DESCRIPTION..."
);

// post to Facebook
try {
  $ret = $fb->api('/!!!Page_ID!!!', 'POST', $params);
  echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook';
} catch(Exception $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

facebook.php:

```
<?php

require_once "base_facebook.php";
class Facebook extends BaseFacebook
{
  const FBSS_COOKIE_NAME = 'fbss';


  const FBSS_COOKIE_EXPIRE = 31556926; // 1 year


  protected $sharedSessionID;


  public function __construct($config) {
    if ((function_exists('session_status') 
      && session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) || !session_id()) {
      session_start();
    }
    parent::__construct($config);
    if (!empty($config['sharedSession'])) {
      $this->initSharedSession();

      // re-load the persisted state, since parent
      // attempted to read out of non-shared cookie
      $state = $this->getPersistentData('state');
      if (!empty($state)) {
        $this->state = $state;
      } else {
        $this->state = null;
      }

    }
  }

  /**
   * Supported keys for persistent data
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected static $kSupportedKeys =
    array('state', 'code', 'access_token', 'user_id');

  /**
   * Initiates Shared Session
   */
  protected function initSharedSession() {
    $cookie_name = $this->getSharedSessionCookieName();
    if (isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
      $data = $this->parseSignedRequest($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
      if ($data && !empty($data['domain']) &&
          self::isAllowedDomain($this->getHttpHost(), $data['domain'])) {
        // good case
        $this->sharedSessionID = $data['id'];
        return;
      }
      // ignoring potentially unreachable data
    }
    // evil/corrupt/missing case
    $base_domain = $this->getBaseDomain();
    $this->sharedSessionID = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
    $cookie_value = $this->makeSignedRequest(
      array(
        'domain' => $base_domain,
        'id' => $this->sharedSessionID,
      )
    );
    $_COOKIE[$cookie_name] = $cookie_value;
    if (!headers_sent()) {
      $expire = time() + self::FBSS_COOKIE_EXPIRE;
      setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, $expire, '/', '.'.$base_domain);
    } else {
      // @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
      self::errorLog(
        'Shared session ID cookie could not be set! You must ensure you '.
        'create the Facebook instance before headers have been sent. This '.
        'will cause authentication issues after the first request.'
      );
      // @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
    }
  }

  /**
   * Provides the implementations of the inherited abstract
   * methods. The implementation uses PHP sessions to maintain
   * a store for authorization codes, user ids, CSRF states, and
   * access tokens.
   */

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   *
   * @see BaseFacebook::setPersistentData()
   */
  protected function setPersistentData($key, $value) {
    if (!in_array($key, self::$kSupportedKeys)) {
      self::errorLog('Unsupported key passed to setPersistentData.');
      return;
    }

    $session_var_name = $this->constructSessionVariableName($key);
    $_SESSION[$session_var_name] = $value;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   *
   * @see BaseFacebook::getPersistentData()
   */
  protected function getPersistentData($key, $default = false) {
    if (!in_array($key, self::$kSupportedKeys)) {
      self::errorLog('Unsupported key passed to getPersistentData.');
      return $default;
    }

    $session_var_name = $this->constructSessionVariableName($key);
    return isset($_SESSION[$session_var_name]) ?
      $_SESSION[$session_var_name] : $default;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   *
   * @see BaseFacebook::clearPersistentData()
   */
  protected function clearPersistentData($key) {
    if (!in_array($key, self::$kSupportedKeys)) {
      self::errorLog('Unsupported key passed to clearPersistentData.');
      return;
    }

    $session_var_name = $this->constructSessionVariableName($key);
    if (isset($_SESSION[$session_var_name])) {
      unset($_SESSION[$session_var_name]);
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   *
   * @see BaseFacebook::clearAllPersistentData()
   */
  protected function clearAllPersistentData() {
    foreach (self::$kSupportedKeys as $key) {
      $this->clearPersistentData($key);
    }
    if ($this->sharedSessionID) {
      $this->deleteSharedSessionCookie();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Deletes Shared session cookie
   */
  protected function deleteSharedSessionCookie() {
    $cookie_name = $this->getSharedSessionCookieName();
    unset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
    $base_domain = $this->getBaseDomain();
    setcookie($cookie_name, '', 1, '/', '.'.$base_domain);
  }

  /**
   * Returns the Shared session cookie name
   *
   * @return string The Shared session cookie name
   */
  protected function getSharedSessionCookieName() {
    return self::FBSS_COOKIE_NAME . '_' . $this->getAppId();
  }

  /**
   * Constructs and returns the name of the session key.
   *
   * @see setPersistentData()
   * @param string $key The key for which the session variable name to construct.
   *
   * @return string The name of the session key.
   */
  protected function constructSessionVariableName($key) {
    $parts = array('fb', $this->getAppId(), $key);
    if ($this->sharedSessionID) {
      array_unshift($parts, $this->sharedSessionID);
    }
    return implode('_', $parts);
  }
}
```

I tried all..... But it isn't showing...
please help me, thanks!!!!!

Comment: can we see `Facebook::api()`?

Comment: Do you have any error to show us? "isn't working" is too broad for give you an answer here

Comment: did you try checking the page as a page admin? what does the api return? we only know that you get "successful", but that´s YOUR string, i assume. you don´t do anything with the response in your code. btw, what version of the php sdk is that?

Comment: (That appears to be version 4 of the PHP SDK, which is very outdated … I’d recommend you use the current v5.)

Comment: ...and if you cannot upgrade because of a lower php version...change your provider ;)